# What is upper copula?

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling, actuarial-science

Could I have a mathematical defintion of the upper copula ?
Is it between two different variable like (X1, X2) or only between same variable (X1, X1) ?

I'm not familiar with this term.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Don't you mean upper tail and lower tail?

Comment: My question was about the term "upper and lower copula". After I don't know if the upper and lower copula are the upper and lower tail...

Comment: Could you provide a reference where you came upon the term?

Comment: Search for this: Fréchet–Hoeffding copula bounds.

Comment: My theory slide :
The Lower and Upper Copula
If ψ(x) = 1 − x, then ψ
−1
(x) = 1 − x, so for u1, u2 ∈ [0, 1]
Cψ(u1, u2) = max(0, 1 − (1 − u1 + 1 − u2))
= max(0, u1 + u2 − 1) = CL(u1, u2)
Note that ψ is not strictly convex!

After I had a problem to solve with Cα the gumbel Copula : If (X1, X2) has copula Cα determine the copula of (X1, X1),

The answer was : The copula of (X1, X1) does not depend on Cα. Actually, it is the upper copula.

Here where I saw the term upper and lower copula.  I don't understand how we can see it is actually the upper copula in this problem.